# Windows 2012 Cluster Validation issue (basic setup)

Tags: windows-cluster

I have two Windows 2012 servers in different data centers (xdc). 
In 1DC server A. in 2DC server B. Both are part of the same domain. Both have remote reg service running and permission for local service is correct. Both have WSFC enabled.

I can validate Server A from either Server A or B.
I can validate Server B from Server B, but if I try to validate from Server A I get an error.

Error: "You do not have administrative privleges on the server B"

I am using domain account for both and I have readded server B o the domain. Have not found why this is failing for this reason.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: same ou? Is uac configured identically?

Comment: Issue was someone setup some rules on one side of the RiverBeds between data centers. Not something I knew they were doing in 2DC. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riverbed blocking rule caused some blocking in 2DC

Comment: Can you please expand on this answer (what rule? How did you isolate the problem? How did you resolve the problem?) As it is this is not likely to be helpful to anyone in the future...

Comment: We do not have the full details right now. We just bypass the two IP addresses from any type of optimization when they are talking to each other. By default the riverbed will try to optimize the traffic
to reduce latency for any tcp connection that passes thru the unit if it see that there is another riverbed unit in the path between the tcp connection endpoints.
We will be researching and finding out why as both data centers have Riverbeds and no idea why from 1DC to 2DC failed, but from 2DC to 1DC was fine. If we find the cause I will post it.